# Java equivalent of C# Array.GetLength(i)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Does Java have a function that gets the length of a specified dimension of a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Java doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays.  What it has is arrays of arrays (etc) but each level can be a different size.

```
int[][] ints = { { 1 }, {1,2,3}, {5,6} };
```

Comment: So would ints.GetLength(0) be equivalent to int.length then?

Comment: Yes. and `ints[0].length` would be 1, `ints[1].length` is 3

Answer (score 7):

No, because Java doesn't *have* multi-dimensional arrays. It only has jagged arrays, i.e. arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said. Java does not have true multidimensional arrays but instead has arrays of arrays. In order to get the length of a particular array you just need to get the length member variable for that array:

```
int[][] ints = { { 1 }, {1,2,3}, {5,6} };
ints[0].length == 1
ints[1].length == 3
```