# does iOs have an equivalent to C# Array.GetLength(int dimension)?

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, multidimensional-array

How can I get multidimensional array, dimension one, length (in objective c)?

In C# it's:

```
Array.GetLength(int dimension)
```

I am looking for the exact equivalent of something like this:

```
int[10,4] mda = new int[10,4];
int A = mda.GetLength(1);
//A=4
```

I know that there are ways to get this without using built in functions..

Comment: Show your code for your multi-dimensional array. There are a few ways this can be done.

Comment: [mda objectAtIndex:i].count;

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637130/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-array-getlengthi?rq=1 is the exact same with +3 votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[mda objectAtIndex:0].count;` It should return the length of the array at index 0 of the multidimensional array.

`[mda objectAtIndex:0].count;` should be same as `mda.GetLength(1)`

Comment: There are no actual dimensional array in objective-c, it will be more of an array of arrays.

Comment: Because i expect that this would return wrong if a jagged array is in question.

Comment: Why am I unable to write _@ACB_ in front??

Comment: @JJ_Jason, I think you just now did it. :) Regarding the jagged array, yes, objective c supports jagged array and not actual multidimensional array and this is the solution for that.

Comment: Not sure what the issue you are facing. It should work. Or else there is always meta site for raising these kind of questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", nil];

int arrayCount = [myArray count]; //arrayCount = 3
```

also accessible with:

```
myArray.count
```

Comment: Where is the first dimension here, as in the second, nested array?

Comment: oh, I didn't understand what he was asking